# Find a and b such that the following piecewise function is differentiable at x = 0

Tags: calculus, derivatives, piecewise-continuity

Find a and b such that the following piecewise function is differentiable at x = 0:

\begin{equation*}
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            ax - b & \quad x \leq 0 \\
            sin(2x) - x^2cos(2/x) & \quad x > 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}

Using the continuity criteria at $ x = 0$ , we can easily find that $ b = 0 $. But when we set the derivatives at $x = 0$ equal to each other, we get this:

a = $ 2cos(2x) $ - $ 2xcos(2/x)$ - $ 2sin(2/x) $

How do we find a I wonder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a = \lim \limits_{h \to 0^+} \dfrac {f(0+h) - f(0)}{h}$

$ = \lim \limits_{h \to 0^+} \dfrac { \sin (2h) - h^2 \cos (2/h) - [f(0)=0]} {h}$

Evaluating this limit, you get $a = 2$